# Jquery each loop doesn't display JSON item's properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

**Edited2:** Here is a pic of how one object looks like. All fields for all objects are filled.
[image: catpicture]

[image]

**Edited:** So the problem appears to be the each loop. I console.logged data and it showed it in an array style. But for some reason, when i try to print the object's age, f.ex., it shows up as undefined.

I am doing a small script for displaying information from a json-file with jquery and ajax. I got the ajax part working (I think) but I can't get my function to print the JSON object data.

So I am trying to display JSON object's with Jquery but it doesn't do anything. The ready function prints out done and complete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.json",
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("done");
        showData(data);        
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});

function showData(data) {   
 $.each(data.cats, function(index, kitty) {         
        var div = $("<div></div>");
        div.addClass("catContainer");        
        
        var image = $("<img></img>");
        image.addClass("catImage");
        image.src="kitty.image";
        
        var header = $("<p></p>").text(kitty.color);
        header.addClass("header");

        var age = $("<p></p>").text(kitty.age);
        var text = $("<p></p>").text(kitty.text);
        text.addClass("text");        
        var price = $("<p></p>").text(kitty.price);        
        div.append(image,header,size,text,price);
        $("div#cats").append(div);
    });       
}
```

I also tried this loop but it prints 'undefined' to the div:

```
$(data).each(function(i, kitty) {
        $('#cats').append(kitty.price);
```

// I am sorry, I am noob. Hope this post is according to the instructions.

Comment: What does your data look like? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: You probably need to `JSON.parse()` the data (jQuery won't do that for you) and you probably need to check whether `$.each` iterates properly.

Comment: first thing do `console.log(data)` inside `showData()` function. also share it here

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax` and you won't have to worry about parsing the response yourself.

Comment: @HamzaRashid it shows all the data in an array looking way. So the data is there. The loop is the problem I think?

Comment: Please share with us what `data.cats` looks like. If `data` is an Array and `cats` is an object in that array, then your each may not work as expected. We need to understand the structure of `data` to be able to assist. Currently, we cannot cause only you know what `data.cats` looks like.

Comment: @Twisty i edited the post above.

Comment: @norepinephrine FYI "JSON" stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It is used strictly to refer to storing a javascript object as plain text. The only thing you can do to JSON is parse the JSON which converts it to actual objects that can be interacted with.

Comment: @norepinephrine assuming this is the `data.cats`, this shows that it is an Array of Objects inside an Array. So you must nest a second loop inside your loop. Again, it's not clear and you should include a better example of your data.

Comment: @Twisty I added a pic of the JSON. how would i do a nested each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is with your `image.src`. When you set it to `"kitty.image"`, this would literally assign that string. So instead of:

```
image.src = "kitty.image",
```

Use:

```
image.attr("src", kitty.image);
```

Or:

```
image[0].src = kitty.image
```

The latter here, since `image` is a jQuery Object, would not have `src` as an index. So we can call `image[0]` to get the HTML Element, that we can then assign the `src`.

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {
  function showData(d, o) {
    $.each(d, function(index, kitty) {
      console.log("Adding Kitty", kitty);
      var div = $("<div>", {
        class: "catContainer"
      }).appendTo(o);

      $("<img>", {
        class: "catImage",
        src: kitty.image
      }).appendTo(div);

      $("<p>", {
        class: "header"
      }).html(kitty.color).appendTo(div);

      $("<p>").html(kitty.age).appendTo(div);
      $("<p>", {
        class: "text"
      }).html(kitty.text).appendTo(div);
      $("<p>").html(kitty.price).appendTo(div);
    });
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "file.json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      showData(data.cats, "#cats");
      console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function(x, e, n) {
      console.log("Error", x, e, n);
    }
  });
});
```

Based on your post, `data` is an Object. `data.cats` is an Array of Objects. So we will iterate the Array with `$.each()` using `data.cats`. I also pass in the target object ID. `.appendTo()` accepts a few items:

> A selector, element, HTML string, array of elements, or jQuery object; the matched set of elements will be inserted at the end of the element(s) specified by this parameter.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/appendto/

It is then just a matter of creating each of the elements. With the `$("<div>")`, jQuery will handle wrapping the element for us. We can also pass in an Object with the attributes, like class. We can chain to the jQuery Object that is the result and would advise using `.html()` versus `.text()`, yet there is nothing wrong with doing either.